# Barplots Not Plotting Frequency Correctly in R

Tags: r, plot

Struggling to plot a barplot where the height of each bar is related to the value in a column (in this case, freq). Table name is `Tag_Count_2`

```
Tag.1  freq
Hello  3
My     4
Name   10
```

I tried:

```
Counts<-table(Tag_Count_2$freq)
barplot(Counts)
```

But it plots the # of times values under Tag.1 share the same freq. I also tried:

```
barplot(Tag_Count_2, height=freq)
```

But it said freq wasn't found.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for

```
barplot(Tag_Count_2$freq)
```

You don't need the table command in this case as you already have the frequency .

Comment: Yes, thank you! And do you know if there's a way to populate the values from tag.1 on the bottom?

Comment: T = c("Hello","My","Name")
axis(1, at=barplot(df$freq),labels=T)
T is basically the column Tag.1 in Tag_Count_2 , so T can also be equal to Tag_Count_2$Tag.1

Comment: I have almost 100...is there a way to somehow do it so that I don't have to cut and paste and put "" around every one?

Comment: You could do tag-count-2$name-of-column

Comment: `barplot` has a `names.arg=` argument - so `with(Tag_Count_2, barplot(freq, names.arg=Tag.1))`